# How to highlight text while typing in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highlighting

I have search box that search project name and project id which is filtered in side bar.

I can able to search and filter the text entered in search box but not able highlight text which have searched.

> Here is the html, css and javascript code which i have tried so far:

**searchbox html code**

```js
      var filterInput, ul, li, a, i;

    filterInput = document.getElementById('filterInput');
    // Add event listener
    filterInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);
     function filterNames(){
      // Get value of input
      let filterValue = document.getElementById('filterInput').value.toUpperCase();

     // Get names ul
      let ul = document.getElementById('projectlist');
 
     // Get lis from ul.
     let li = ul.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item');

     // Loop through collection-item list
      for(let i = 0;i < li.length;i++){
       let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
       // If matched
       if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1){
        li[i].style.display = '';
        var text=a.innerHTML;
        text = text.replace( filterValue, '<span class="search-found">' + 
     filterValue + '</span>' );
        a.innerHTML=text;
        
      } else {
       li[i].style.display = 'none';
      
      }
     }
     }
```

```css
  .sidebar .nav-link .highlight {

    background-color: #7b9d6f;
 
    }
```

```html
  <input id="filterInput" class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">

Here is the project list html code:

      <div id="projectlist" class="sidebar-sticky" >
    <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills">
     
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">
          <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="../static/image/generic_gcp.png">
          Project 1
          <div>
            <small>
            ProjectId: 1
          </small>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item" >
        <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">
          <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="../static/image/generic_gcp.png">
          Project 2
          <div>
            <small>
            ProjectId: 2
          </small>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item" >
        <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">
          <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="../static/image/generic_gcp.png">
          Project 3
          <div>
            <small>
            ProjectId: 3
          </small>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Please Help me the Hightlight the code

Comment: you want the text that typed in search will be highlight in dropdown??

Comment: exactly, search text will not drop down it will list in side bar ..

Comment: now tell me what do you want ?  if i type 1 project 1 should be highlight . and rest will be apper as normal ? right

Comment: that what i asked him, explain us !

Comment: @לבנימלכה what Kakul sarma said was right..

Comment: @לבנימלכה any updates

Comment: @PvDev do you use bootstrap 4

Comment: @ yep...........

Comment: please confirm my edit

Comment: what do you mean highlight? color/background/bold???

Comment: @לבנימלכה text background color\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170778/discussion-between---and-pvdev).

Comment: @PvDev see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [hilitor](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/) for kinda similar project and it was fine. Simple and open source build with pure JavaScript.

Here is your example.. I've changed your structure a bit:

```js
// Get input element
let filterInput = document.getElementById('filterInput');
// Add event listener
filterInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);

function filterNames() {
    // Get value of input
    let filterValue = document.getElementById('filterInput').value.toUpperCase();

    // Get names ul
    let ul = document.getElementById('projectlist');
    // Get lis from ul
    let li = ul.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item');

    // Loop through collection-item lis
    for(let i = 0;i < li.length;i++) {
       let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

        // If matched
        if(a.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
         li[i].style.display = '';
        } else {
         li[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

// Call Hilitor
var myHilitor2;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
 // Set the parent
 myHilitor2 = new Hilitor("nav-item");
 // Text direction
 myHilitor2.setMatchType("left");
}, false);

// Event
document.getElementById("filterInput").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
 myHilitor2.apply(this.value);
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/GerHobbelt/hilitor/master/hilitor.js"></script>

<div id="projectlist" class="sidebar-sticky" >

 <input id="filterInput" class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">

 <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item" >
   <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">
    <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="../static/image/generic_gcp.png">
    <p class="inner">Project 1</p>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" >
   <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">
    <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="../static/image/generic_gcp.png">
    <p class="inner">Project 2</p>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" >
   <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">
    <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" src="../static/image/generic_gcp.png">
    <p class="inner">Project 3</p>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/GerHobbelt/hilitor) and you can learn more about its options in the [documentation](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/)

Answer (score 1):

Please add class in that a tag and add css for this
like

```
if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1){
        li[i].style.display = '';
        var text=a.textContent;
        text = text.replace( filterValue, '<span class="search-found">' + 
     filterValue + '</span>' );
        a.textContent=text;
         a.classList.add('bold-class');
      } else {
       li[i].style.display = 'none';

      }
```

And in style

```
.bold-class{
 font-weight:bold
}
```

Comment: You'd be better using `node.textContent` instead of `innerHTML` so you can allow for successive filtering: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: it does not highlighting and now search also not working

Comment: hey priya it works fine but when giving backspace it does not filtering properly...

Comment: I can't see this issue on your snippet

Answer (score 1):

AS I see in your code you add `span` with `class="search-found"` **BUT** you worte in your css diffrent class `.highlight` **THAT DOES NOT EXIST** 
change your css:

```
.search-found {

    background-color: red;

    }
```

```js
  var filterInput, ul, li, a, i;

    filterInput = document.getElementById('filterInput');
    // Add event listener
    filterInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);
     function filterNames(){
      // Get value of input
      let filterValue = document.getElementById('filterInput').value.toUpperCase();

     // Get names ul
      let ul = document.getElementById('projectlist');
 
     // Get lis from ul.
     let li = ul.querySelectorAll('li.nav-item');

     // Loop through collection-item list
      for(let i = 0;i < li.length;i++){
       let a = li[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
       // If matched
       if(a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterValue) > -1){
        li[i].style.display = '';
        var text=a.innerHTML;
        text = text.replace( filterValue, '<span class="search-found">' + 
     filterValue + '</span>' );
        a.innerHTML=text;
        
      } else {
       li[i].style.display = 'none';
      
      }
     }
     }
```

```css
.search-found {

    background-color: red;
 
    }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input id="filterInput" class="form-control form-control-dark w-100" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">



      <div id="projectlist" class="sidebar-sticky" >
    <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills">
     
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">
          <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" >
          Project 1
          <div>
            <small>
            ProjectId: 1
          </small>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item" >
        <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">
          <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%" >
          Project 2
          <div>
            <small>
            ProjectId: 2
          </small>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item" >
        <a name="{{.ProjectID}}" class="nav-link" href="#">
          <img class="img-fluid" style="width:8%">
          Project 3
          <div>
            <small>
            ProjectId: 3
          </small>
          </div>
        </a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: It does not highlight more than one text

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a working example
https://codepen.io/silabhijit/pen/bMvXgm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover">
    <title>Highlight Text while typeing in input box</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: verdana;
        }

        .page-content {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 990px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        input {
            padding: 10px;
            width: 350px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 15px 0 0 0;
        }
        ul li {
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
            padding: 10px;
            border-bottom: 0;
        }

        ul li:last-child {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;;
        }

        ul li strong {
            color: #ff0000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <header class="page-header">
        </header>
        <main class="page-content">
            <div class="input-holder">
                <input type="text" class="model" />
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>Abhijit Sil</li>
                <li>Abhishek Roy</li>
                <li>Abhi Sen</li>
                <li>Ranjit Sharma</li>
                <li>Ravi Kar</li>
                <li>Surojit Shil</li>
                <li>Arunayan Shil</li>
            </ul>
        </main>
        <footer class="page-footer">
        </footer>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.model').on('keyup', function() {
                    var val = $(this).val();

                    var listItems = $('ul li');
                    listItems.each(function() {
                        var itemVal = $(this).text();

//                        remove strong tag from original string
                        itemVal = itemVal.replace('<strong>', '');
                        itemVal = itemVal.replace('</strong>', '');

                        if(itemVal.indexOf(val) !== -1) {
                            var convertedString = "<strong>" + val + "</strong>"
                            var output = itemVal.replace(val, convertedString);
                            $(this).html(output);
                        } else {
                            $(this).html(itemVal);
                        }

                    })
                })
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```